# NSComboBox - Obtaining selected information and NSComboBoxDataSource

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nscombobox

For the life of me, I am being continually stumped with `NSComboBox`.

I created an object that conforms the `NSComboBoxDataSource` protocol, and implemented:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInComboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox;
- (id)comboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox objectValueForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

I set the instance of my `NSComboBox` to use a Data Source, and set this object as the source. That works great, my implementation returns the number of items, and returns an `NSString` value for an item at specific indices.

Then I decide that I want to do something when something is selected, this is where my problems begin. There is no obvious method to override in the `NSComboBoxDataSource` protocol to handle the selection of items in the combo box.

So, I also have my object conform to `NSComboBoxDelegate` and implement:

```
- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

Unfortunately, unlike `NSTableView` on selection, the notification's object is the `NSComboBox` not the object of the item selected. "Fine" I tell myself, I will call the `NSComboBox` method:

```
- (id)objectValueOfSelectedItem;
```

This should return the item that is selected and I can go from there. However, that method is to be called ONLY when `usesDataSource` is set to `NO`, which is not my case. Warnings start flying when I use this.

So, my question is, what is the proper way to handle `NSComboBox` selections when you are using a data source?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you want [indexOfSelectedItem](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSComboBox/indexOfSelectedItem) instead of objectValueOfSelectedItem. Then since you're the data source you should be able to call your own `comboBox:objectValueForItemAtIndex:` method.